# UPNP dlna_framework sample code required?

Tags: android, upnp

I am working on UPNP network devices.

I want to get all the devices from network with particular name and manufacturer id.

So i am able to do the same by some library like dlna_framework getting response from some posts.  I have this framework but issue is that I am not able to use this framework. any sample code or example will help me out!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What framework are you trying to use?  Can you update your question to include the code you've written so far?  If you haven't written any code, you could restate your question instead. In particular, more information on what you understand "particular name and manufacturer id" to mean would be important.

Comment: you can check open source library for android . This is developed by taking reference of cling. I need sample demo application to use this library code

Comment: you can download from dropbox link :                                 https://www.dropbox.com/s/e78fqmqzspkq4jj/dlna_framework.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to try the Cling UPnP stack.

> This is user manual:[Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/support/manual/cling-support-manual.html).

Hope it is useful for you.

Comment: [BeyondUPnP](https://github.com/kevinshine/BeyondUPnP).This is an open source app,base on Cling.